# mongodb java query where clause for date

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am new to MongoDB and not sure how to achieve the below.
One of the document from the collection,

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("56cf4cf2997964f0d91aa373"), 
    "id" : "A", 
    "status" : "open", 
    "createdTime" : NumberLong(1456426212898)
}
```

I would like to fetch data with the following where query,

where - `status` is open && (`createdTime` + 10 mins) < currentTime

The below code works for the `status`. But not sure how to include the time as shown above.

```
for open `status` - {"status":"open"}
```

Java code,

```
    final Bson statusFilter = eq("status", "open");

    final Document projection = new Document();

    final Document sort = new Document();
    sort.append(CREATED_TIME, -1);

    final FindIterable<Document> operation = collection.find(filter).projection(projection).sort(sort);
```

But not sure, how to achieve ( `createdTime` + 10 mins) < currentTime.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be

```
{ $and:[{ "status":"open"},{"createdTime":{$lt:new Date().getTime() - (1000 * 60 * 10)}} ] }
```

The query is similar to `where status=open && createdTime<(currentTime-10mins)`

Note: `createdTime+10mins < currentTime` can be written as `createdTime < currentTime-10 mins`

Comment: This answer is accepted. But would like to  know how to use the filed in the query like createdTime+10mins.